# Applying shared context only when all metadata filters apply with RSpec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, tdd, rspec2

With RSpec, if I define a shared context as follows:

```
shared_context :a => :b, :c => :d do
  # ...
end
```

It will get attached to the example group if either `metadata[:a] == :b` or `metadata[:c] == :d`. **Is there a recommended way to attach the context only if *both* the conditions apply?**

As for now, I resorted to changing the filter to read:

```
shared_context :a => proc { |v, m| v == :b && m[:c] == :d } do
  # ...
end
```

But I can't imagine this being the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

metadata components are or'd by design, and there's no first-class approach to what you're doing, so that's as good as any.

If you have some ideas about how we could enforce that all the metadata matches, please file a feature request at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues and we can discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

I started my shared_context with

```
shared_context "freeze time", workday: true, time: "19:00" do
 ...
end
```

But than in, this case, I rewrited code to use single metadata like

```
shared_context "freeze Time at workday after 18:00", workday_time: "19:00" do
  before{ 
    hours,minutes = "19:00".split(':')
    Timecop.freeze(Time.local(2013,04,01,hours.to_i,minutes.to_i)) 
  }
  after{ Timecop.return }
end

shared_context "freeze Time at weekend before 18:00", weekend_time: "10:30" do
  before{ 
    hours,minutes = "10:30".split(':')
    Timecop.freeze(Time.local(2013,04,06,hours.to_i,minutes.to_i)) 
  }
  after{ Timecop.return }
end
```